# Drawing easeljs radial gradient strokes

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm trying to implement some more fancy canvas drawing, such as something that looks more like a brush stroke. I ran into and awesome resource (http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/), but I'm having some troubles converting it to syntax that works with easeljs.

Original Example: http://codepen.io/kangax/pen/FdlHC

My Attempt: http://codepen.io/mcfarljw/pen/Jifzk

```
var currentPoint = { x: event.stageX, y: event.stageY };
  var dist = distanceBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);
  var angle = angleBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);
  drawingCanvas.graphics.setStrokeStyle(5, 'round', 'round');
  for (var i = 0; i < dist; i += 5) {
    x = lastPoint.x + (Math.sin(angle) * i);
    y = lastPoint.y + (Math.cos(angle) * i);
    drawingCanvas.graphics.beginRadialGradientStroke(["#F00","#00F"], [0, 1], x, y, 5, x, y, 10)
  }
  lastPoint = currentPoint;
  stage.update();
```

It's not producing any errors, but it's also not drawing anything on the canvas. Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version is almost complete, expect that you missed the most important part of actually drawing the (current part of the) line:

```
drawingCanvas.graphics.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
drawingCanvas.graphics.lineTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
```

If updated your code-pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fCcEJ

Comment: Silly mistake on my part, definitely gets the line going. I must be overlooking something even bigger because it's still a bit off from the nice brush like feel of the original example.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve that with `beginRadialGradientStroke` - you should use the radial-gradient-fill like they do in the original example. Take a look at this fork, maybe that will help you understand how `beginRadialGradientStroke` works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLKiI

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was completely overlooking the fact that the fillRect was used.